# 'vagrant ssh -c COMMAND' behavior differs from running commands inside a 'vagrant ssh' session

Tags: bash, ssh, gruntjs, vagrant

This works:

```
vagrant ssh
cd /vagrant && grunt build
```

This doesn't:

```
vagrant ssh -c 'cd /vagrant && grunt build'
```

(exits with `bash: grunt: command not found`)

Why?

Reason I'm asking is that I have a shell script that deploys a site to GitHub Pages, and I wanted to add a build step at the beginning to get a fresh build right before deployment.

I also tried writing a shell script `vagrant_build.sh` like:

```
cd /vagrant
grunt build
```

and having vagrant run it with `vagrant ssh -c 'bash /vagrant/vagrant_build.sh'`, but it still can't find `grunt`.

The docs say that `vagrant ssh -c COMMAND` runs a single command, do I need to take that 100% literally? I was interpreting it as 'anything you can fit in one line in a terminal'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

because `grunt` is not in your `vagrant`'s path. so give it absolute path.

```
cd /vagrant && /path/to/grunt build
```

Comment: Interesting, any idea why the nodejs shims get loaded with `vagrant ssh` but not with `vagrant ssh -c COMMAND`? Does the `~/.bashrc` not get loaded on the latter?